# Airflow: How to get the current date of when data is inserted into a BigQuery table?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am inserting data from a GCS Bucket to BigQuery, and I am unsure how to get the current date of when the data is inserted into a column.

This is my schema:

```
load_csv = gcs_to_bq.GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id='gcs_to_bq_example',
    bucket='cloud-samples-data',
    source_objects=['SOURCE-FILE-LOCATION'],
    destination_project_dataset_table='airflow_test.gcs_to_bq_table',
    schema_fields=[
        {'name': 'item', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
        {'name': 'date', 'type': 'DATE', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
    ],
    write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    dag=dag)
```

So, in my schema, I have `item` and `date`.

Therefore, when triggering my DAG to insert the data from the GCS Bucket to BigQuery, how do I make it so that the `date` column contains the current date of when the data gets inserted?

For example, if I insert it today, then the `date` column should be `2022-11-24`.

Comment: You need to have the current date, that means the date field is not given but the `GCS` file ?

Comment: I have the GCS file with the date field, but I want the current date inside that column

Comment: Your input file is a `csv` or `json` ?

Comment: ```.csv``` is my file

Answer (score 1):

There might be 2 ways to reach the desired result but not sure of either.

The first one is to use default values as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/default-values) and add a column to your schema:

```
schema_fields=[
    {'name': 'item', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
    {'name': 'date', 'type': 'DATE', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},

    {'name': 'load_date', 'type': 'DATE', 'default': 'CURRENT_DATE'},
]
```

However, this is pre-GA so not sure whether you can use it (also I haven't tested sorry).

Other possibility would be to use Airflow templating ability and add another step:

```
load_csv = gcs_to_bq.GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
task_id='gcs_to_bq_example',
bucket='cloud-samples-data',
source_objects=['SOURCE-FILE-LOCATION'],
destination_project_dataset_table='airflow_test.gcs_to_bq_table_{{ ds_nodash }}',
schema_fields=[
    {'name': 'item', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
    {'name': 'date', 'type': 'DATE', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
],
write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
dag=dag)
```

With this operation you'll get your file in a table, with the ingestion date (or timestamp if you use `ts_nodash`) in the table name. You're then free to use the `BigqueryOperator` to insert this staged data into your destination data with some SQL.

Comment: @AnandP2812 did this solve your issue?

Comment: I can explicit further if required. Otherwise please mark the question as solved for the next people looking for similar issues 